# How can the energy released when bonds formed be harnessed to do work?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I'm trying to understand how living organisms get energy from food. I've heard that "energy is released when bonds form", but what exactly does "released" mean?

If the energy dissipates in the form of heat, then how can the cell use it for things?

If the energy is not in the form of heat, what form does it take?

Comment: You might get a better answer on the Biology site.  The search term is "molecular motors". It's complicated; in the simplest cases, the energy just directly turns a tiny crank.

Comment: google ATP (Adenosine triphosphate), that is the most important molecule involved, should give you some useful sources explaining the main principles. Short, simple answers are no substitute for the real stuff, imo, to appreciate the complexity involved.

Answer (score 3):

In most reactions the energy is released as kinetic energy of the reaction products. If you consider some reaction:

$$ A + B \rightarrow C + D $$

then if you add up the kinetic energies of $A$ and $B$ before the reaction and add the kinetic energies of $C$ and $D$ after the reaction you'll find that the kinetic energy after the reaction is higher than before it.

Kinetic energy is basically heat, and while this is great if you're trying to run a steam turbine it's pretty useless if you're a cell. Fortunately there is a type of reaction called a [redox reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox) where the energy goes into exciting electrons. Redox reactions all involve pumping electrons around, and it's the energy of the electrons that cells can use to drive other reactions.

My knowledge of biochemistry is too sketchy to say much more, but one type of redox reaction you'll certainly be familiar with is the battery. Batteries use redox reactions to raise the energy of electrons, and that's how they power electrical circuits. Cells aren't like electrical circuits, but they use the energy of redox reactions in the same way to power the reactions they need to live.

Comment: Interesting! 1) Why is kinetic energy higher in the products? Thinking about it mechanically, if two particles start at rest, accelerate toward each other, and then collide, won't they end at rest as well? 2) So is it accurate to say that increasing kinetic energy of molecules is not useful to a cell, but increasing the energy of electrons is?

Comment: @EliRose: re (1) energy must be conserved so if two particles collide they cannot just stop enless there is some way to get rid of their initial kinetic energy. If the reaction is [endothermic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endothermic_process) then it can absorb some of the kinetic energy, but it would be unlikely to be so precisely balanced as to absorb all the kinetic energy. If the reaction is [exothermic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exothermic_reaction) then the products must speed away with increased energy for energy to be conserved.

Comment: Re (2) I fear I've given you a rather facile description of an enormously complicated situation. It's true that living organisms use redox reactions extensively, but they use lots of other reactions as well.

Comment: That's okay, I think I'm comfortable chunking the concept off as "molecular motors" for now. I suppose I'm still curious about why some reactions are endothermic and some are exothermic -- does one need quantum mechanics to explain this?

Answer (score 0):

The released energy does indeed take the form of heat, which is why fire is hot.

Cells use this energy to heat another molecule over the the threshold at which it will have an endothermic reaction, thus allowing them to force a reaction which would not normally occur at room temperature, or simply to heat the body, mantaining body heat even in an environment that is not as hot.

The reaction in particular that is used for this purpose is ATP -> ADP + P.
The produced ADP is then converted back into ATP while heated by the esothermic reaction C6H12O6 (sugar) + 6*O2 -> 6*CO2 + 6*H2O. This process is called cellular respiration.